# jQuery UI multiple sortable columns : issue with scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery : 1.9.1

jQuery UI : 1.10.1

[Please See The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rakcheru/77YkB/)

```
            <td class="my-column" >
                <div id="my-div1" class="my-div-class">
                    <p class="para-item"> para 101 </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="my-div1" class="my-div-class">
                    <p class="para-item"> para 201 </p>
                </div>
            </td>

<script>
    $(".my-div-class").sortable( { connectWith: '.my-div-class' } );
</script>
```

In the fiddle, when user tries to drag top item in list-1 into bottom of list-2, the scroll bar of list-1 gets moved instead of list-2 scroll bar.

Tried various things but couldnt make it to work properly. Any inputs/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: It seems like the dragged element isn't properly leaving the first container. Try playing with hover events of the two drop areas to "move" the element from one container to the next so that the scroll behaves properly.

Comment: Also, you're using conflicting IDs in your html markup. Remember, IDs must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gallen. Sure, i will try to play around hover events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to change the actual src file. There is a handle as part of the option

please see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77YkB/8/)

```
    sort:function(event,uiHash){

    var scrollContainer = uiHash.placeholder[0].parentNode;
        var overflowOffset = $(scrollContainer).offset();
    if((overflowOffset.top + scrollContainer.offsetHeight) - event.pageY < scrollingSensitivity) {
scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop + scrollingSpeed;
    } 
    else if(event.pageY - overflowOffset.top < scrollingSensitivity) {
        scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop - scrollingSpeed;
    }
    if((overflowOffset.left + scrollContainer.offsetWidth) - event.pageX < scrollingSensitivity) {
scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft + scrollingSpeed;
    } 
    else if(event.pageX - overflowOffset.left < scrollingSensitivity) {
        scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft - scrollingSpeed;

}
    }
```

Comment: Works nicely!. Thanks a lot. I just had to disable sortable's scroll functionality to fix a small issue. Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/77YkB/9/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the _mouseDrag function of jquery.ui.sortable.js //Do scrolling is on scrollParent where the parent is the container of the dragged element. But parent should be the container of where you about to drop. I moved the scroll changes below this._contactContainers(event); instead of this.scrollParent[0]. I used this.currentContainer.element[0] which give you the actual container and worked..

```
if(this.scrollParent[0] !== document && this.scrollParent[0].tagName !== "HTML") {
   this.overflowOffset = this.currentContainer.element.offset();
   var scrollContailer = this.currentContainer.element[0];
   if((this.overflowOffset.top + scrollContailer.offsetHeight) - event.pageY < o.scrollSensitivity) {
    scrollContailer.scrollTop = scrolled = scrollContailer.scrollTop + o.scrollSpeed;
   } else if(event.pageY - this.overflowOffset.top < o.scrollSensitivity) {
    scrollContailer.scrollTop = scrolled = scrollContailer.scrollTop - o.scrollSpeed;
   }
   if((this.overflowOffset.left + scrollContailer.offsetWidth) - event.pageX < o.scrollSensitivity) {
    scrollContailer.scrollLeft = scrolled = scrollContailer.scrollLeft + o.scrollSpeed;
   } else if(event.pageX - this.overflowOffset.left < o.scrollSensitivity) {
    scrollContailer.scrollLeft = scrolled = scrollContailer.scrollLeft - o.scrollSpeed;
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the fix and the inputs. Though that definitely works, i am looking for a way where i dont have to touch the jquery-ui source. Will update if i find something. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is the following code:

```
$("#foo, #bar").sortable({
  connectWith: ".foobar",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.sender) {
      widget = ui.sender.data("ui-sortable");
      widget.scrollParent = $(this);
      widget.overflowOffset = $(this).offset();
    }
  }
});
```