# Sortable scroll issue with connected lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, scroll

I have an issue with jQuery UI sortable plugin, for some reason, it fails to scroll correctly when used with connected overflowed, scrollable lists.

Please take a look at this [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xogujaca/1/edit?html,output)

Now, the issue is when you try to drag list item from List 1 to List 2 (or the opposite) and drag it to the bottom edge (or top, if I am trying to drag it to top), the List 1 will scroll instead of List 2. I tried my luck with scroll, scrollSensitivity, scrollSpeed but had no luck with these options.

I appreciate any help with this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this had already been discussed in this thread
[jQuery UI multiple sortable columns : issue with scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794882/jquery-ui-multiple-sortable-columns-issue-with-scrolling?rq=1)

user1555614 solution solved my problem.